# Pull IDX stocks with alphavantage?

Tags: equities, data, market-data

How do I pull data for stocks on the indonesian stock exchange (https://www.idx.co.id/en-us/market-data/stocks-data/list-of-stocks/) with alphavantage? What is the symbol I should pass? I've tried for example `IDX:AALI`, `IDX.AALI`, `AALI.IDX`, `AALI:IDX` but none work.

Comment: Alphavantage is only for US stocks

Comment: I've used it for all kinds of asian stock exchanges (india/china/japan/HK etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap in your API key below.  Keep in mind that they are priced in Indonesian Rupiah's.

For Indonesia you need to use the **Jakarta** exchange symbol:

AALI: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=AALI.JK&apikey=your_api_key

Comment: This is no longer working

Comment: @KardiTeknomo I answered the question when it was written. I can't control 3rd party API changes. If you have a similar problem, perhaps you can pose a question that someone can answer...